What is the topology of the zero set of this quadratic form?
Consider a quadratic form in $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined as $q(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2$. I am trying to gain as much intuition as possible about the set of vectors such that $q(x) = 0$.
One thing that can be said about it is that we can characterize these vectors as follows: Write $v = (x_1, x_2)^\top, u = (x_3, x_4)^\top$. Then, $q(x) = 0$ if and only if there exists a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix $R$ such that $v = R u$. This is because $q(x) = \|v\|^2 - \|u\|^2$ and $R$ preserves norms.
Now, given a specific $R$, the space of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $v = R u$ is 2-dimensional since orthogonal matrices are invertible. These spaces are not disjoint, however, as for a given pair $v, u$ there may exist more than one orthogonal matrix $R'$ that satisfies $v = R' u$.
Following the previous comments, we can think of the zero set of $q$ as a collection of 2-dimensional vector spaces, one for each matrix $R$ in the orthogonal group in 2 dimensions, namely $O(2)$. This group is a Lie group, so we have a vector bundle.
Is there anything to be gained about $q$ by considering its zero set as a vector bundle over $O(2)$? What about in more dimensions? What about on the complex numbers instead of the reals?
I'm really interested in anything at all that can be said about $q$, though most pointedly in its topology and geometry. Thanks!

This (singular) quadric is a cone over a torus ($S^1\times S^1$). A linear change of variables will show that the intersection of $q(x)=0$ with the unit sphere is a torus.

Interesting! Could you please expand on that?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus#Formal_definition

Note that with your $u$ and $v$, the intersection of $q(x)=0$ with the unit sphere is given by $\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2=1$ and $\|u\|^2=\|v\|^2$, so we have $\|u\|=\|v\|=1/\sqrt2$.  The set of such $(u,v)$ is $S^1\times S^1$ (circles of radius $1/\sqrt2$).  Every nonzero point of $q(x)=0$ satisfies $q(x/\|x\|)=0$ and so $x$ is a scalar multiple of some point on that torus.
